# Default Date Time Format date_diff

Tags: php

date_diff not support d/m/Y format. Currently I using strtotime to convert date to m/d/Y but I want to know the way to change date_diff date format to d/m/Y ?

Thank you.

Comment: This is nothing to do with `date_diff()`.... it's when you're creating a DateTime object...... PHP treats a `/` separator as US format, a `-` separator as European format..... as [documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).... otherwise, how would it know whether `2/3/2016` was 2nd March or 3rd February? And `strtotime()` is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd/m/Y', '14/05/2016' );  # oo style
$date2 = date_create_from_format( 'd/m/Y', '17/05/2016' );     # procedural style

$dateInterval = $date1->diff( $date2 );
```

or:

```
$dateInterval = date_create_from_format( 'd/m/Y', '14/05/2016' )->diff( date_create_from_format( 'd/m/Y', '17/05/2016' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_create` along with `date_diff`

```
$datetime1 = date_create('10/11/2009');
$datetime2 = date_create('10/13/2009');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: So how can use date_diff with d/m/Y. Like 14/05/2016 ? date_create("14/12/2016") not working.